# Using my backup disk

Tags: usb, hard-drive, backup, cp

I have made an Ubuntu backup using a 3.5' internal HDD hooked up to a SATA-USB adapter with power supply, and I formatted it to FAT.

I can't seem to transfer normal files onto it, as when I try to drag files onto it this doesn't work. If I try to do it via command line my error is as follows:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/mnt/sdf/WT_data_norm.txt': Permission denied
```

Is this because the backup disk can't be used as a normal USB storage device as well?

Comment: FAT32 is not a good format for backup of Linux files. It really is only for smaller devices. It has no journal for making recovery easy if file corruption and cannot have a file over 4GB. If only your data, you could use NTFS, but lose Linux ownership & permissions. If just data you can reset. But system files have many different owners,not just root and many different sets of permissions.  For Linux use ext4.http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: I did this so that I could also use the disk to transfer files from a Mac to my linux computer. Are there any formats that would be suitable for this?

Comment: I have read that Windows cannot format drives and partitions larger than 32GB in FAT32.

Comment: Check who owns the drive. Normally, if you use your desktop to mount  a plugged in USB device, it is mounted in /media/<your_id>/<some_name> and you are made the owner. Otherwise, mounted FS are owned by root by default, so you cannot write to them without changing rights or ownerships.

Comment: Chances are it only has root permissions. Navigate to `/media/user-name/disk-name`. Then r. click on the *disk-name* and then click *Permissions* tag. Who is the *Owner*? What permission is shown for *Others* ?

Comment: Yes you are right, it is owned by root. However when I try to change this (and yes I remembered to do sudo) I get the following error that I don't know how to rectify. Please could you help?

chown: changing ownership of 'sdf/': Operation not permitted

Comment: You can't change permissions while drive is mounted so unmount it first. Check permissions for `/media`. If this shows as root owned you need to change ownership to yourself, using `sudo chown  -R  username /media`, Remount drive and check its permissions again to ensure you now own it..

Comment: This seems to be a permissions issue of the drive itself, and I can't seem to fix this. Furthermore, backups no longer work, and I think I am affected by the following bug, so I suppose I need to reformat the drive and wait for a bug fix: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1770929